# Segmentation fault at the end of the C program

Tags: c

Is the segmentation fault at the end of the code (just to allocate memory to 2D array and print the result)? The last `printf` statement is being printed and any code that I add at the end runs successfully and then segfault appears.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,i,j,**mat;

    printf("\nEnter the size of the square matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    *mat = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *)); 

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      mat[i]= (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++) printf("%d\t",mat[i][j]=rand()%10*i+j);
      printf("\n\n\n");
    }

    printf("Bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Technically `*mat` in 8th line (printed in code) should be `mat`, but then everything is fine. The code mentioned compiles (with obvious warning of incompatible pointer type in gcc) and works except at the end when it prints segfault.
Had there been a segfault in the program, it wouldn't had run till the end!

Comment: One possible explanation is that the return address from `main` has been overwritten on the stack, this is why it gives the segfault at the end of `main` function; probably because of wrong pointer usage.

Comment: Since you apparently know that "`*mat` in 8th line (printed in code) should be `mat`", what exactly is your question?

Comment: Your use of `*mat` invokes undefined behaviour.  The variable `mat` is uninitialized; you dereference it.  Anything can happen.  The code is broken.  In any case, you should have been using `mat = malloc(n * sizeof(*mat));` unless you're using a C++ compiler to compile C, in which case you need the cast in there.

Comment: Can you try this? Before the `*mat=` statement, add `printf("%p %p\n", &j, mat);`. Tell us the output.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick While debugging, i tried to add printf statements to get the addresses and i was surprised to see that adding printf statement(not to print anything but &mat ) eliminated segfault. The printf("%p %p\n", &j, mat); doesn't make any change in output. Very confusing(i am new to C).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can undefined behaviour successfully give same result consistently always. I just ran the code in infinite loop to check it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i am curious to know the reason of such behaviour. *mat can also act as a pointer (though incompatible)  to array of pointers to n 1D arrays

Comment: @man_stack, `*mat` designates a different object than does `mat` -- or it would do if `mat` held a valid pointer to allocated memory.  It is `mat` that needs to be assigned a value at that point, and the assignment to `*mat` has no effect whatsoever on `mat`.  Moreover, since at that point `mat` does not point to any object, the assignment to `*mat` produces undefined behavior, as JonathanLeffler already observed.  That's where the explanation must end: the whole idea of undefined behavior is that C does not define what it is.

Answer (score 4):

```
*mat = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

should be

```
mat = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

Unless I change the line to this, the program segfaults right there. Through sheer luck and undefined behaviour your program manages to run for a little longer.

Also there is no need to cast the return value of malloc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) are a couple reasons why you probably shoudn't.

Comment: He already know this: *"Technically *mat in 8th line(printed in code) should be mat"*

Comment: Beat me too it >.< That mallocing error doesn't explain why his code still runs until the last `printf` statement, though.

Comment: @SpencerDoak: undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including things apparently working far better than you've any right to expect.  That seems to be happening here.

Comment: O.K. even if i change the syntax as suggested except *mat, the program works showing that required memory was allocated.

Comment: Such is the case with undefined behaviour. For your own sanity just focus on fixing and understanding errors, don't dig too deep into it, unless you're into software security.

Answer (score 3):

To actually answer your question, the reason you are getting a segmentation fault **after** the end of the main() function is because the stack has been corrupted.

The [stack pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_register) has been overwritten, which means that when main() attempts to return, the stack pointer contains an invalid value.  This causes your program to attempt to access memory from outside the process's address space.  If you use exit(0) you *may* avoid the segmentation fault altogether.

Keep in mind that your program results in an undefined behavior.  Sometimes you'll get a segmentation fault at the end, sometimes during execution, sometimes none at all (And all sorts of other weird things may happen).

Comment: While debugging, i tried to add printf statements to get the addresses and i was surprised to see that adding printf statement(not to print anything but &mat ) eliminated segfault.      printf("%p \n",&mat);  Also i ran the code no. of times in an infinite loop; it's consistent.

Comment: Did you add the printf statements after the allocation of map in the loop? (Line 13 in main).

Comment: P.2  just before *mat = malloc(n*sizeof(int *));

Answer (score 1):

`*mat = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));` is dereferencing an un-allocated pointer. This causes *undefined behavior* ...

*Undefined* means anything can happen. Have a read of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1294207) It is certainly possible that you are not seeing the results of your bad de-allocation until the end of your program.

As a further note, [you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).So the following:

```
*mat = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
mat = malloc(n * sizeof mat*);
```

Along with some modifications to the rest of your memory allocation lines.

Comment: Further: suggest the style of `mat = malloc(sizeof *mat * n);`.